# Perl Parse $1 from ARGV

Tags: regex, perl

Is it possible to parse a $1 from ARGV in Perl?
I am trying to parse a passed in $1 from ARGV, but its treating it as a literal string, rather than the $1.

This is just a simple script trying to show proof of concept.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $from = '^(.*/)([^/]*)$';
my $dir = "/var/foo/baz";
$dir =~ /$from/;

# This works and prints the expected output I would like
print "Dir $1\n";
print "File $2\n";

# This is printing a literal '$1' and '$2'
print "Dir $ARGV[0]\n";
print "File $ARGV[1]\n";
```

This is what I am running and my output:

```
$ ./test.pl '$1' '$2'
Dir /var/foo/
File baz
Dir $1
File $2
```

Comment: You have indeed given the literal '$1' and '$2' as arguments. Even if you substitute these with any thing else, say '$3' and '$4', the first case of Dir and File will work right and in the second case, you will get the literals.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [String::Substitution](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?String::Substitution).

```
$ perl -E'
    use String::Substitution qw( interpolate_match_vars last_match_vars );

    my ($str, $pat, $x_template, $y_template) = @ARGV;
    $str =~ $pat
       or die("Didn'\''t match\n");

    my $x = interpolate_match_vars($x_template, last_match_vars());
    my $y = interpolate_match_vars($y_template, last_match_vars());

    say "x: $x";
    say "y: $y";
' \
    abcdef '(.)c(.)' '$1' '$2'
x: b
y: d
```